# Installing Wireless Drivers

Tags: raspbian, wireless, software-installation, driver

I am having trouble understanding how to install the drivers needed for my usb wireless that came with my Raspberry Pi Starter Kit. I have the drivers from the CD on the SD card.

install.sh does nothing. I even right-clicked it and changed it's property to be an executable and after that it still doesn't do anything.

This is the contents of the folder where the install.sh is found.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/RTL818_Wireless $ ls
android_reference_codes              readme.txt
android_reference_codes_ICS_nl80211  ReleaseNotes.pdf
document                             WiFi_Direct_User_Interface
driver                               wireless_tools
hardware_wps_pbc                     wpa_supplicant_hostapd
install.sh
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/RTL818_Wireless $
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What does the readme.txt file contain cat readme.txt?

Answer (score 1):

Most Wi-Fi adapters (especially ones that come in Pi starter kits) should work out-of-the box. Try plugging it in, then opening "Wi-Fi Config" from the desktop. (You can open the desktop by typing `startx`)

If there is a need to install extra drivers, and it comes with a .sh script (like you mentioned), try using the following command: (I assume you are on Raspbian, as you tagged it with that)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/RTL818_Wireless $ sudo install.sh
```

Also note that not all scripts generate an output. It may have done something, but just without telling you. Try plugging the adapter in, and it should work.